# C# Order a list of labels by location on screen

Tags: c#, winforms, list, location

How can I order a list of labels by their location on screen?
My labels move around the screen but only in X axis, this is the code that I have but I notice it isn't working.

```
 labels.OrderBy(x => x.Location.X);
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit: This is how I'm testing if it works or not...

```
 private void actualizarPosicoes() {

        labels.OrderBy(x => x.Location.X);

        MessageBox.Show(labels.First.Value.Text.ToString());


    }
```

But I want to use it when a label is removed from the screen but first I have to make the OrderBy working.

```
 private void reorder(Label lb) {

        labels.OrderBy(x => x.Location.X);
        var it = labels.GetEnumerator();

        var node = it.Current;
        while (it.MoveNext())
        {
            var nextNode = it.MoveNext();
            if (nextNode != null)
            {
                if (nextNode.Equals(lb))
                {
                    nextNode = it.MoveNext();
                    it.Current.Location = new Point(node.Right, 0);
                }
            }
            node = it.Current;

        }


    }
```

I have a global linkedlist called labels:

```
private LinkedList<Label> labels;
```

Comment: How do you know its not working?

Comment: What part of it isn't working? Do they all have the same parent control? or do they belong to different controls? How are you getting the initial list prior to the sort?

Comment: Post more of your code please mate, not enough to go on at all. The only thing I can guess at is that you need to reassign the value of `labels` the result of your `OrderBy`. i.e. `labels = labels.OrderBy(x => x.Location.X);` But it's just a guess until you provide more context.

Comment: it returns new Enumerable with ordered list, what you want to do?

Comment: @I'm ordering the list and sending the message with the text of the first label of the list after the sort

Comment: @JoãoSilva you are trying to align all labels in a row without empty space between?

Comment: @Sergey Yes... when the user Remove a message from the screen I want to reorder it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as container to your labels. Removing any label will automatically re-arrange other labels.

Here is sample - assume you have `labelsFlowLayoutPanel` to host labels and `addLabelButton` to add labels:

```
private void addLabelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    label.DoubleClick += label_DoubleClick;
    labelsFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(label);
}

void label_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = (Label)sender;
    labelsFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(label);
    label.DoubleClick -= label_DoubleClick;
}
```

Each time you click `addLabelButton` new label is created and inserted to the right of other labels. Double-clicking on any label will remove it and re-arrange other labels.

Further info - [Windows Forms Controls Lesson 5: How to use the FlowLayout Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb798028)

Comment: I had the FlowLayoutPanel before and that didn't work as I needed so I had to create my own custom panel...

Answer (score 0):

Without offering any suggestions for a better approach, and to answer the question directly, the problem with you code is as follows:

The `OrderBy` method with not modify the instance is is called on, it will instead return a new `IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>` where `TSource` is the type of object, for example `Label`. This means that your code should look like this:

```
labels = labels.OrderBy(x => x.Location.X);
```

Depending on what type of object `labels` is, you may need to convert it to a `List` like so:

```
labels = labels.OrderBy(x => x.Location.X).ToList();
```

---

**EDIT**: I just realized you are using `LinkedList`, I would recommend changing this to `private List<Label> labels;`

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it!
There is the answer if anyone else need it...

```
private void reorder() {

var it2 = labels.OrderBy(x => x.Location.X);
Label orderLb = it2.ElementAt(0);

for (int i = 1; i < labels.Count; i++)
{
    it2.ElementAt(i).Location = new Point(orderLb.Right, 0);
    orderLb = it2.ElementAt(i);
}
```

Thank you all for the help, really appreciate it!